# Create DataSource dynamically in multi-tenancy using Spingboot

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-data, multi-tenant

I'm trying to implement multi-tenancy architecture in my project. I am referring "http://anakiou.blogspot.com/2015/08/multi-tenant-application-with-spring.html" example. Everything is working fine in this example. But problem in this example is whenever new datasource to be add then we should add it manually. But i want something like adding datasource dynamically without application restart.

This is my application.properties

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
spring.thymeleaf.cache=false

spring.datasource.datasource1.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/tenant_1
spring.datasource.datasource1.username=root
spring.datasource.datasource1.password=root
spring.datasource.datasource1.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

spring.datasource.datasource2.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/tenant_2
spring.datasource.datasource2.username=root
spring.datasource.datasource2.password=root
spring.datasource.datasource2.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

This is DataSourceConfig.java

```
package com.anakiou.mt.config;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Primary;

@Configuration
public class DataSourceConfig {

@Autowired
private MultitenancyProperties multitenancyProperties;

@Bean(name = { "dataSource", "dataSource1" })
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource.datasource1")
public DataSource dataSource1() {
    DataSourceBuilder factory = DataSourceBuilder

.create(this.multitenancyProperties.getDatasource1().getClassLoader())
             .driverClassName(this.multitenancyProperties.getDatasource1().getDriverClassName())
            .username(this.multitenancyProperties.getDatasource1().getUsername())
            .password(this.multitenancyProperties.getDatasource1().getPassword())
            .url(this.multitenancyProperties.getDatasource1().getUrl());
    return factory.build();
}

@Primary
@Bean(name = "dataSource2")
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource.datasource2")
public DataSource dataSource2() {
    DataSourceBuilder factory = DataSourceBuilder
            .create(this.multitenancyProperties.getDatasource2().getClassLoader())
            .driverClassName(this.multitenancyProperties.getDatasource2().getDriverClassName())
            .username(this.multitenancyProperties.getDatasource2().getUsername())
            .password(this.multitenancyProperties.getDatasource2().getPassword())
            .url(this.multitenancyProperties.getDatasource2().getUrl());
    return factory.build();
}
}
```

MultitenancyProperties.java

```
package com.anakiou.mt.config;

import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.NestedConfigurationProperty;

@ConfigurationProperties("spring.datasource")
public class MultitenancyProperties {

@NestedConfigurationProperty
private DataSourceProperties datasource1;

@NestedConfigurationProperty
private DataSourceProperties datasource2;


public DataSourceProperties getDatasource1() {
    return datasource1;
}

public void setDatasource1(DataSourceProperties datasource1) {
    this.datasource1 = datasource1;
}

public DataSourceProperties getDatasource2() {
    return datasource2;
}

public void setDatasource2(DataSourceProperties datasource2) {
    this.datasource2 = datasource2;
}

}
```

DataSourceBasedMultiTenantConnectionProviderImpl.java

```
package com.anakiou.mt.util;

import org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.spi.AbstractDataSourceBasedMultiTenantConnectionProviderImpl;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

@Component
public class DataSourceBasedMultiTenantConnectionProviderImpl extends 
AbstractDataSourceBasedMultiTenantConnectionProviderImpl {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 8168907057647334460L;
private static final String DEFAULT_TENANT_ID = "tenant_1";

@Autowired
private DataSource dataSource1;

@Autowired
private DataSource dataSource2;

private Map<String, DataSource> map;

@PostConstruct
public void load() {
    map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("tenant_1", dataSource1);
    map.put("tenant_2", dataSource2);
}

@Override
protected DataSource selectAnyDataSource() {
    return map.get(DEFAULT_TENANT_ID);
}

@Override
protected DataSource selectDataSource(String tenantIdentifier) {
    return map.get(tenantIdentifier);
}
}
```